# Error while Importing Moment.js to HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, momentjs

When I try to import Moment.js to a HTML document using

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.4/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I get this message in browser console every time: (Both tested in Firefox and Chrome)
`Uncaught Error: failed to require "moment/moment"`
What causes this error?

I've tried CDNJS, Unpkg and JSDelivr. I've also tried previous versions of Moment.js.

Comment: Probably shouldn't be doing it like that, if you're using node. Read mode [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/)

Comment: Does console return you the error when you import moment or when you try to use it? And how do you use it?

Comment: @AlTheLazyMonkey The console returns error when I just import.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I am only using HTML and JS. I embedded the npm package into webpage by <script> tag.

Comment: Can you create a simplified fiddle or pen of your issue, just so we can try and find out what's causing it?

Comment: @FiddlingAway Here is it: https://jsfiddle.net/sL5a9ct3/

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the moment-jalaali library. Take a look at [this alternative](https://github.com/fingerpich/jalali-moment). Here is a version of your fiddle, with jalaali-moment [instead](https://jsfiddle.net/tg290uw7/). Can you check, and see if the conversions are done correctly?

Comment: @FiddlingAway it seems the conversions are fine. Never thought that the problem was moment-jalaali. Please answer the question so I can mark it as correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the problem is within the moment-jalaali library. As an alternative, you could try the [jalaali-moment](https://github.com/fingerpich/jalali-moment) library (some of the moment-jalaali authors are involved as well).

For testing purposes, you can try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tg290uw7/) - your code has been adapted to use the jalaali-moment library. The fiddle contents are also in the following SO snippet.

```js
var d = new Date()
    var jalaali = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-AU-u-ca-persian', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
      timeZone: 'Europe/Istanbul'
    }).format(d).split('/');
    var hijri = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-AU-u-ca-islamic-umalqura', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
      timeZone: 'Europe/Istanbul'
    }).format(d).split('/');
    var month = parseInt(hijri[1]);
    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        month = 'Muyaram';
        break;
      case 2:
         month = 'Safar';
        break;
      case 3:
        month = 'Rabamah';
        break;
      case 4:
        month = 'Rabafer';
        break;
      case 5:
        month = 'Jazamah';
        break;
      case 6:
        month = 'Jazafer';
        break;
      case 7:
        month = 'Rajab';
        break;
      case 8:
        month = 'Shaban';
        break;
      case 9:
         month = 'Ramadan';
        break;
      case 10:
        month = 'Shawil';
        break;
      case 11:
        month = 'Zulqat';
        break;
      case 12:
        month = 'Zulgach';
    }
    var jalaaliMoment = moment(d, 'jD/jM/jYYYY');
    var result = hijri[0] + '/' + jalaaliMoment.jDayOfYear() + ' ' + month + ' ' + jalaali[2];
    document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Irshatovan Calendar</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2 id="dt"></h2>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.4/min/moment.min.js"></script><!-- Moment.js importing problem. -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jalali-moment/dist/jalali-moment.browser.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```